# Anypoint Studio/Eclipse debugging - Watch value shows as null. How to show actual value of watch?

Tags: eclipse, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

When running Mule Debugger, the variable value of the highlighted object shows "United" but the watch at

```
payload.'1'.typedValue.value[0].airlineName
```

shows `null` as in the screenshot below.

How to show the actual value of the watch, "United"?

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The attribute typedValue of type [TypedValue<>](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/special-parameters#typedvaluetype) is probably an implementation detail that is probably not meant to be used outside the MuleSDK. Try adding a watch for `payload.'1'[0]` or `payload.'1'.value` to see if that can be interpreted.